# Are there differences between the original Metal Gear Solid and the one from the PSN Store?

Tags: version-differences, metal-gear-solid

I have the original Metal Gear Solid game for the PS1 (which was my brother's). However, I'm missing the first disc of the game, so I'm stuck with the second disc which I can't really start off with. On the other hand, I bought a Super Slim PS3 last month, and I was told that the first game is available on the PSN Store for $10.

I remember that years ago, Metal Gear Solid was re-released for the Gamecube and named *The Twin Snakes*. There were a handful of differences between the PS1 and Gamecube version, like the voice acting and the script which are the only things I can recall for the time being, and from what I've heard, the Gamecube version wasn't as good as the PS1's.

So I guess I'm just wondering if the PSN Store's edition of the game is based off of *The Twin Snakes*, or if it's the real thing with the original one for the PS1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The version available on the PSN is the original PS1 version, without updated graphics or such. *The Twin Snakes* was a GC exclusive and isn't available on any other platforms.

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear that. Thanks! Guess I might be buying it off of the store then.